# Invexity of the $L_2$ norm

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, norms

I have the following function:
$ f({\bf A,b}) = \| {\bf y - XAb} \|_2^2$
where ${\bf y}_{n \times 1}$ and ${\bf X}_{n \times p}$ are fixed, and ${\bf A}_{p \times r}$ and ${\bf b}_{r,1}$ are the variables ($r \leq \min(p,q)$).

Is the function $f$ invex (defined [here](http://benisrael.net/INVEXITY.pdf)) in both $\bf{A}$ and ${\bf b}$? In other words, is there a function $\eta$ such that

$f(({\bf A, b}) + \lambda \eta({\bf A, b, C, d})) \leq \lambda f({\bf C, d}) + (1-\lambda) f({\bf A,b})$

In the very simple case where $p=q=n=r=1$, $y=0$, and $x=1$, we get the function $a^2b^2$ which is invex.